# How do I pass bootstrap dropdownlist items using jquery in MVC from view to controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I attempting to pass string items from two bootsrap dropdownlists and a search textbox to an MVC controller from a view.  i want to send the text from each of the two selected dropdown-menu items and the string from the search box to the controller.  How do I accomplish this using JQuery/Ajax?  Below is what I have tried:
View:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top: 0px;">
     <div class="contianer-fluid" style="text-align: left;">
         <div class="jumbotron" id="mainJumbo" stlye="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" id="progress">
             <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="btn-group">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded+ "false">Search Type: <span class="selection">Fuzzy</span><span class="caret"></span>
                         </button>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="searchType">
                             <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-value="Fuzzy">Fuzzy</a>
                             </li>
                             <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-value="Literal">Literal</a>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="btn-group">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded+ "false">Specific Fields: <span class="selection">None: </span><span class="caret"></span>
                         </button>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="specField">
                             <li><a>None</a>
                             </li>
                             <li><a>spec2</a>  @* This is not part of the real code.  There are actually several auto-populated li items here *@
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-trm" id="srch-trm" /> <a id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

The Script:

```
 <script>
      $(function () {
           $("#submitButton").on('click', function () {
                var searchType = $('#searchType li a').val();  //I have tried several different ways of doing this and nothing has worked.  This was the last thing I have tried.
                var specField = $('#specField li a').val();
                var searchTerm = $("srch-term").val();
                $.ajax({
                     url: '@Url.Action("_Search", "Home")',
                     type:'Post',
                     data: {
                     searchType: searchType,
                     specField: specField,
                     searchTerm: searchTerm
                },
                success: fucntion(result) {
                     $("mainJumbo").html(result);
                     }
                });
            });
         });
 </script>
```

Comment: You don't have any controls in your view except the input with `id="srch-trm"`.  Using `.val()` gets the value of an `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>`). You can use `.text()` to get the text value of the `<a>` tag but its a little unclear what you are trying to do. How are you actually generating this html?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I want the selected dropdown-menu item text to be passed.  I have tried with .text() and it returns " ".

Comment: I actually tried it this way again, but using .text() and it worked.  I'm not sure what happened, but maybe I tried ,text() with the several previous attempts and forgot with this one.  Thank you.  If you give an answer I will give you the check.

Comment: Your html does not include a `<select>` tag! Are you just trying to generate this html manually? Have you created a `<select>` tag (using say `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and applied the plugin to it.

Comment: ACTUALLY, that did NOT do the trick.  Id didn't give me the selected item, it gave me the text of all items.

Comment: No I do not have <select> tags.

Comment: That why I could not understand what you are trying to do. You need a `<select>` Are you using a jquery plugin? e.g. [Bootstrap-Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: No Jquery plugin.  OK, but that creates a select picker instead of the dropdownlist.  I want to be able to select an item from each of the two lists, and the text from the search box and when the submit button is clicked, pass the string values for all 3 to the controller.

Comment: Its still unclear what you trying to do. What do you mean _"instead of the dropdownlist"_. It is creating a dropdown list. I assume your getting your terminology wrong. It appears your generating something like [this example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dropdowns-within-buttons) which is a menu and is designed to redirect to another page when you click on an item. A menu has no 'selected' value. If you want to make a selection from available items and post back their values, you need a `<select>` which generates a dropdownlist.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can explain it any better.  I was able to make it work using you r <select> tag suggestions.  It doesn't look how I want it to, but it works.  The bootstrap dropdownlist has a different look and is structured different in html than the select list.  imagine a search box with two dropdownlists.  The user selects "fuzzy," or "literal" from one dropdownlist and can select a specific field to serach, or all fields from the second dropdown list.  The user can type a search keyword into the search box.  Selecting from these lists does nothing until the search button is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean the _"The bootstrap dropdownlist"_? What control are you referring to. If its [this one](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dropdowns-within-buttons) then that NOT a control used for selecting an item - its a menu for redirecting to another page.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out.  I like the syle of it.  No worries, your way works, so if you want to write that in an answer I will give you yhe credit.  Just make sure you state that you cannot use the dropdown-menu that I ask about in the question and that you have to use the select list.